# get main product category list woocommerce

Tags: plugins

I am using woo commerce theme for my site. I am trying to display a list of main product category list. I tried this code. But it returns all the main and sub categories.

```
$product_category = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
```

I need to display just the main product category list. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Check the parent of each category, top-level terms will have a parent value of 0:

```
$product_category = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

foreach( $product_category as $cat ):
    if( 0 == $cat->parent )
        echo $cat->name;
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can very easily do so using woocommerce shortcodes

`echo do_shortcode('[product_categories number="12" columns="4"]');`

if you want the shorcode to show all categories do so:

`echo do_shortcode('[product_categories number="12" columns="4" parent="0"]');`

I believe I have made it clear enough for you to understand.

You can also take a look at how it's done in content_product-cat.php and use your own custom loop, the shortcodes above will output the content of this file btw.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code.

It's working for me..

```
<?php
$term = get_queried_object()->term_id;
$termid = get_term($term, 'product_cat' );

        $args = array(
            'orderby'       => 'name', 
            'order'         => 'ASC',
            'hide_empty'    => false, 
            'child_of'      => $term, 
            'parent'        =>0
        ); 
    $subproducts = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args);
    foreach ($subproducts as $subproduct) { 
    echo $subproduct->name; ?>
```

Comment: Please don't just dump code, perhaps [edit] and add some explanation how this might solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

taken from here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777929/woocommerce-how-do-i-get-the-most-top-level-category-of-the-current-product-ca/#answer-20778095

```
function get_root_term() {

global $post;
$prod_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ($prod_terms as $prod_term) {

    // gets product cat id
    $product_cat_id = $prod_term->term_id;

    // gets an array of all parent category levels
    $product_parent_categories_all_hierachy = get_ancestors( $product_cat_id, 'product_cat' );  

    // This cuts the array and extracts the last set in the array
    $last_parent_cat = array_slice($product_parent_categories_all_hierachy, -1, 1, true);
    foreach( $last_parent_cat as $last_parent_cat_value ) {
        $root_term = $last_parent_cat_value;
    }
}
return $root_term;
}

// usage 
$root_term = get_root_term();

if ( $root_term === 27 ) {
// do something
}
```